# how to calculate the next occurrence interval of a packet if you know that it follows the poisson distribution?

Tags: matlab, frame, packet

Suppose that you have some computer stations, these computer stations are sending packets to a network.

Now the transmission time of a packet takes S seconds
the amount of packets that all the computer stations will send follows the poisson distribution

so the probability that L packets will be generated at a given frame time is Pr[k] = ( λ^(L) * e^(-λ) )/(L!)

Now, I want to simulate this by calculating at each step the next occurrence interval, which is the interval when the next packet will be generated by a station.

I found some code and I took the equation which is this:

```
            next_occurrence_interval= 1/λ  * log(1/(1-rand))
```

If I remember correctly rand gives a random number from 0 to 1. I'm trying to understand, what exactly is this and where does this equation come from so that I will be able to use it in my network simulation program that I'm trying to program.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Poisson process, which describes a process where events happen independently with a given average rate. I seem to recall this means the interarrival times will follow an exponential distribution.

Now lets look at your formula. Note that since rand returns a uniform number between 0 and 1, 1-rand is the same thing. That part is irrelevant! That is rand is equivalent to 1-rand.

Ok, so next, look at the expression you found. As I said, what you wrote is equivalent to

```
next_occurrence_interval = 1/λ  * log(1/rand)
  =  1/λ  * (log(1) - log(rand))
  =  1/λ  * (-log(rand))
```

Around now, you MIGHT start to recognize this as how one generates an exponentially distributed random number.

Comment: Most random() implementations return a number from [0, 1). So, finding the difference `1 - random()` avoids the undefined `ln(0)`.

Comment: @erickson - You misunderstand the entire point. The question was what is this doing? My argument shows WHY this is generating exponential variates. The 1-rand simply confuses the issue, and is effectively irrelevant except when a zero occurs - an event with vanishingly small probability anyway.

Comment: No, I don't misunderstand the entire point. I'm just pointing out a practical concern *on a programming question.*

Comment: @erickson: And not all random generators return a number on the half open interval. In fact, in MATLAB, which is where the question applies to, the samples live in the interval (0,1). (See help rand.) Therefore your comment is indeed totally irrelevant. This is NOT a concern in MATLAB.

Comment: >> help rand:    
 rand Uniformly distributed pseudorandom numbers.
    R = rand(N) returns an N-by-N matrix containing pseudorandom values drawn
    from the standard uniform distribution on the open interval(0,1).

Answer (score 0):

It's the [exponential distribution.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) Use the formula `-ln (1 - random()) / λ,` where *λ* is the average number of events per unit of time.